# Prevent Edge browser hiding HTTP error pages

Tags: microsoft-edge

Microsoft's Edge browser has a "friendly error page" feature similar to Internet Explorer's, where it masks a server's non-success responses (e.g. 400 Bad Request) with its own "friendly" pages.

You can observe the behaviour by using Edge to visit here: http://httpstat.us/400

Whilst this is a better user-experience than being presented with highly technical default server error pages, it's an unwanted experience when you want to return an actual page with a non-success status code.

In Internet Explorer, as long as the server returned more than 512 bytes of data in the response, it would display the response, but in Edge, that's not enough.

Is there a way to coerce Edge to display the "error" content returned by the server when a non-success status code is returned? I don't want to reconfigure the browser, just convince it that my response is "friendly" enough to present to the user.

Comment: answered your below. hope it helps. thanks

Comment: After deleting the cookies and history, it worked again ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove the "friendly errors" at the moment. You can use the F12 developer tools for debugging. 
Nevertheless, the friendly page includes the actual HTTP response code so you can have an idea. Also, if you require more details you can check the full details on the request/response using the F12 Network tool to get the data the server is responding with.

Answer (score 0):

> In Internet Explorer, as long as the server returned more than 512 bytes of data in the response, it would display the response, but in Edge, that's not enough.

In experimenting, I found that this is indeed enough (example [here](https://www.hackcraft.net/error/badrequest/) of working 400 page).

I also though found that if you had previously sent a response of 512 characters or less, and then fixed the response to be greater, refreshing the page or following a link to it would still get the "friendly" (with friends like these, who needs enemies?…) message. Entering the URI in the address bar again (i.e. just focusing in the address-bar and hitting enter) was necessary to make the error page actually appear.